# Name of the following integral identity

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, terminology

I remember the following integral identity but not sure of the name. I tried to search all the names I remember (like beta integrals, gamma integrals, etc.) but couldn't find for the one given below.

If someone knows the name, please leave an answer.

$$\int_0^{\infty } x^n e^{-b x^m} \, dx = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{m})}{mb^{\frac{n+1}{m}}} $$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Are you sure about that factor of 1/2 in front?  You can obtain this equation — without the factor of 1/2 — by substituting $u = b x^m$ and using the definition of the gamma function.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it has a name. Do you have a reason to suspect that it does?

Comment: The factor of $\frac12$ is clearly wrong viz. the special case $b=m=1$. @MichaelSeifert It should be $\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: I found the equation from an old notebook, As it appears the 0.5 factor is wrong, let me correct it in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we have to restrict the value of $b$ to $b>0$ and the value of $n$ as $n>-1$, otherwise the integral would not converge at all. Now enforcing the substitution $bx^m\mapsto x$ we obtain the following

\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-bx^m}\mathrm dx&=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac xb\right)^{\frac nm}e^{-x}\left[\frac1{b^{\frac1m}}\frac1mx^{\frac1m-1}\right]\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac1{b^{\frac{n+1}m}}\frac1m\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{n+1}m-1}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac1{b^{\frac{n+1}m}}\frac1m\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}m\right)
\end{align*}

> $$\therefore~\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-bx^m}\mathrm dx~=~\frac1{b^{\frac{n+1}m}}\frac1m\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}m\right)$$

Your given identity is almost right, to be precise only the factor $1/2$ has to be replaced by $1/m$. However, hence this is only a straightforward application of the substitution $bx^m\mapsto x$ I have doubts that there is a separate name for this identity.